documentationPluginsBootstrapper error in spring fox
We are on spring boot 2.7.18 and spring fox springfox-swagger2.version = 2.9.2 based microservice project, during running of server below error is received.
Im trying to resolve this issue from several weeks, searched in net and stack over flow from several weeks.
Applied all the solution like

Checked all the version of springfox-swagger2.version from 2.9.2 to 3.0.0
Added springfox MVC library in the pom.

3.Added spring.mvc.pathmatch.matching-strategy=ant-path-matcher
still not able to resolve the issue.
Please help us to resolve the issue.
Error
[main] [11ef5327f513571b97c200ffb15384cf] ERROR o.s.boot.SpringApplication - Application run failed
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'documentationPluginsBootstrapper'; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.condition.PatternsRequestCondition.toString()" because the return value of "springfox.documentation.spi.service.contexts.Orderings.patternsCondition(springfox.documentation.RequestHandler)" is null
at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:182)
at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.access$200(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:54)
at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor$LifecycleGroup.start(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:357)
at java.base/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75)
at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.startBeans(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:156)
